# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap JPAQuery

Tags: java, spring, querydsl

So I want to use JPAQuery to make filtration in my spring app but this line:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

JPAQuery <Customer> jpaQuery = new JPAQuery<>(em);
```

is throwing:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Multimap
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.google.common.collect.Multimap at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ...
> 72 more

Comment: You need add the dependency of the target class first and check if there is still the same issue.
The lib should be Guava dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this piece of code is not making this specific error and somehow you are importing this class somewhere else, if you really need it make sure to properly import it with your dependency management system (maven, gradle) otherwise try to find which component is using this class and remove it.

Comment: that's te only one place where Im using it

Comment: It could be the only place where you are using the JPAQuery, yes, but if you look to the error message that you got there is related to another class (Multimap) from google commons, and that's the class that I'm referring to, so somewhere on your code you are importing that class Multimap and you need to find it, either to properly import it into your system or to remove it.